bend P-Trap 90 degree?
Weir section of the trap, can I bend 90 degree as shown below?
I found a post saying that is legit, but isn't there is another rule, that horizontal to horizontal must use a long 90 degree fitting? But the turn on a p trap certainly isn't long 90...
https://www.reddit.com/r/Plumbing/comments/r7gdof/p_trap_rotation_is_it_legit_to_rotate_a_p_trap/




You can turn the exit pipe portion of the trap in whichever way is most convenient. That turn is not horizontal to horizontal, it is horizontal to vertical, whichever way it is oriented.

Yep, once the water is going up from the 180º turn, it doesn't care whether it goes 90º left, right, forward or back (except back would be quite the feat of physics).


Yes, this is the entire point of the tubular trap with two rotating compression joints. Along with slip joints on the tail and arm, and a saw, you can do almost anything so long as the drain isn't too high.
The horizontal to horizontal rule is for a closed DWV fitting carrying flowing water. The trap is open to air on one side and water isn't flowing, it is pushed out by gravity until there is just the right amount left.

